# Bash while loop stops for no reason?

Tags: bash, while-loop

I run the following bash script to rotate my mobile phone vids

```
while read filename ; do
    nf=$(echo $filename |rev | cut -f1 -d '/'|cut -f2- -d '.' |rev)
    echo $nf
    rm -f ffmpeg2pass-0.log
    rm -f rotate/tmp.avi
    ffmpeg -i $filename -c:v libxvid -pass 1 -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 4 -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2" "rotate/tmp.avi"
    ffmpeg -i $filename -c:v libxvid -pass 2 -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 4 -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2" "rotate/$nf.avi"
done <rotatelist_2
```

I know there are better ways to do this; I budged this together but I'm figuring out how to do the videos right so the rest don't need to look nice ;-))

However after the first run, the loop unexpectedly ends with no error message. I run similar loops for other things which work pretty well.

The echo is not called again so I guess there's something wrong with the loop itself. The linebreak in the list is a 0x0A, so it should be ok.

Comment: What are the contents of `rotatelist_2`?

Comment: Does any of the commands within the loop read standard input too?  If so, it ate the rest of `rotatelist_2`.  It looks like it would have to be `ffmpeg` that does that, so I don't rate it highly as a possibility.  You could use `while read -u 3 filename; do ...; done 3<rotatelist_2` and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: That ugly second line can be replaced using `basename`. This assumes the filename extension is always the same, if it isn't, something like `${x%.*}` will do (details under *Remove matching suffix pattern.* in the bash man page)

Comment: While we're kibitzing -- lots of bugs here that would be fixed by adding more quotes. `"$filename"` will deal with spaces, glob characters, etc. within names correctly; bare `$filename` won't. http://shellcheck.net/ will do the work of finding bugs of this variety for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
</dev/null ffmpeg ...
</dev/null ffmpeg ...
```

or

```
ffmpeg ... </dev/null
ffmpeg ... </dev/null
```

to prevent ffmpeg reading from rotatelist_2 via stdin.

Comment: The other approach is to redirect from the file (and then read) on a FD other than stdin.

Comment: Yes,  Jonathan Leffler's solution is smarter.

Comment: [That's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55682533/why-read-command-in-shell-script-is-missing-initial-characters#comment98049447_55682555) even better.