# bash while read loop and stdin - force nested command's stdin to tty?

Tags: bash

I've finally run into the surprising stdin behavior when piping into a while read loop.

Consider the following:

```
find . | while read file; 
do
  echo "==[$file]==";
  cat;
done
```

In this instance, `cat`is just a stand-in for any command that receives input from STDIN.  It's surprising (to me at least) that `cat`'s STDIN is actually coming from `find`, so it gobbles up the rest of the `find` output.

Suppose one wanted to interact directly from the tty with the command in `cat`'s place.  E.g. Suppose instead of `cat` you wanted to run a script which might ask questions you wanted to respond to interactively (`"<file> exists: Overwrite? [y/n]"`).

Is there a way to force the inner command's STDIN to be the tty?

I've found a lot of similar questions, including this: [Why redirect stdin inside a while read loop in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650892/why-redirect-stdin-inside-a-while-read-loop-in-bash)

But I couldn't understand the answer well enough to get it to work.

(edit: in light of clarifications to that other question, I'm now considering this a duplicate of that question.)

Comment: What part of the other answer, *specifically*, was hard to follow? (I actually just fixed up the code to add some comments less than an hour ago; was hoping that would be sufficient on its own).

Comment: ...seriously, though -- followup describing how exactly the other answer didn't address your question would be greatly appreciated. (One possibility is that we'll get a clearly distinct new question created here -- but the other one, of improving the original sufficient to make it more useful, also adds value to the site).

Comment: It's simply that your bash is so much stronger than mine.

I read your answer before you added the code comments.  It helped me understand that `cat`'s stdin was gobbling everything up from the `find`, which I hadn't understood.  I voted it up, which probably triggered you adding the comments.

I'd done `2>&1` before and roughly understood it but this stuff is all foreign to me:  `exec 3</dev/tty || exec 3<&0; exec 3<&-`. I tried adding that stuff to mine but it didn't work for me (because I left out the `<&3`).

The comments help me understand it better.

Comment: I'd be content marking this question as a duplicate of the other one, but I'm not sure how. My S.O. is apparently as weak as my bash.  :)

Comment: It *is* a useful duplicate, though -- looking at both, I think you've asked a question with fewer complicating factors, and thus allowed a similarly improved answer. Thank you for that. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm replacing `cat` with something a little less problematic in the examples below:

```
read_a_line() { local line; read -r line; echo "Read line: $line"; }
```

That way it only reads *one* line of input per loop invocation, rather than reading all the way to EOF. Otherwise, though, I'm trying to keep changes minimal to focus on the immediate problem.

See [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for a discussion of why it's preferable to redirect from a process substitution into your loop rather than to pipe to a loop.

---

First, you can simply redirect from `/dev/tty`

```
find . | while read file; 
do
  echo "==[$file]=="
  read_a_line </dev/tty
done
```

---

Second, you can copy stdin to a different file descriptor, and reuse it later:

```
exec 3<&0  # make FD 3 a copy of FD 0
find . | while read file; do
  echo "==[$file]=="
  read_a_line <&3
done
exec 3<&- # close FD 3 now that we're done with it
```

---

Third, you can try to do *both* -- attempting to make FD 3 (or any other FD of your choice above 2) be open to /dev/tty, but making it a backup of your original stdin if that fails.

```
exec 3</dev/tty || exec 3<&0
find . | while read file; do
  echo "==[$file]=="
  read_a_line <&3
done
exec 3<&-
```

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer.  I've now gotten solutions #1 and #2 working in my situation. As I commented on the original question, I didn't understand in the solution in the other thread until you added the code comments; it's clearer now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This example could help:

```
{
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    read -u3 -p "what to do with: [$file]?> " action
    printf "got [$action] for the [$file]\n\n"
done < <(find . -print0)
} 3<&0
```

- for the whole script's the stdin is reditected to fd3
- and internal `while` is redirected from the `find`
- the `read` reads from the fd3 - e.g. from the terminal

Comment: Is there a reason that it's `( )`s on the outside, rather than `{ }`s (avoiding the performance overhead of a subshell, while still allowing scoped redirections?)

Comment: ...actually, what's being added by that extra syntax that just a `3<&0` directly after the `done` wouldn't accomplish?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the `{}` is better :) but, like 2ms overhead....

Comment: Sure, I agree, on any modern machine it's completely trivial when not in a tight loop (and you wouldn't want to spawn `find` in a tight loop anyhow).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy for me the extra `{}` mean - it is cleaner... - sure could be done shorter and nicer..