# bash script won't loop over lines in file when certain command executed

Tags: bash, loops, rosbag

My script reads a list of ".bag" files from a textfile supplied as an argument. and does something with each one.
(for clarity, I have omitted most of the "stuff")

```
while IFS= read -r bag
do

    echo Extracting from $bag

    # Play the script for saving the images
    python2 extract_imgs.py --image_topics "$image_topics" --basepath "extracted_imgs/$bag_name" &
    extract_imgs_PID=$!

    # play the bag file
    rosbag play -r 10 $bag

    echo rosbag play returned: $?
    echo finished playing $bag

    # kill the subscribe node
    kill $extract_imgs_PID

done < $1
```

If I comment out the `rosbag play -r 10 $bag` line, this script behaves as I expect: It reads each line from $1 and runs an iteration of the loop with that line set as $bag.

But with the 'rosbag play -r 10 $bag' line, it works correctly for the first line, but then exits the loop and finishes. Why? the return status of `rosbag play` is `0`. How can I get this script to run the rosbag play command and then continue looping over the lines of the input file?

Comment: Probably `rosbag` is reading from stdin, stealing lines from `read`. See [Why redirect stdin inside a while read loop in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41650892/4518341) and [Shell script while read line loop stops after the first line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13800225/4518341)

Comment: Also [BashFAQ #89: I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)

Comment: yep that was it, thankyou!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell script while read line loop stops after the first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800225/shell-script-while-read-line-loop-stops-after-the-first-line)

Comment: that is the same problem but the Accepted Answer does not apply here, as there is no such "-n" flag for rosbag play.

Comment: See the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55334788/4518341) then

Comment: yes, the second answer is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the same as:

[I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)

so the solution was to redirect stdin:

```
rosbag play -r 10 $bag </dev/null
```

Answer (score -1):

I will offer a solution, with the disclaimer that the solutions which I offer normally don't get very well received around here; but anyway...

```
#!/bin/sh -x

init() {
cat >> edprint+.txt << EOF
1p
q
EOF

cat >> edpop+.txt << EOF
1d
wq
EOF

next
}

next() {
[[ -s stack ]] && main
end
}

main() {
filename=$(ed -s stack < edprint+.txt)
python2 extract_imgs.py --image_topics "$image_topics" --basepath "extracted_imgs/$bag_name" &
    extract_imgs_PID=$!
rosbag play -r 10 ${filename}
echo "rosbag play returned: $?"
echo "finished playing ${filename}"
ed -s stack < edpop+.txt
next
}

end() {
rm -v ./edpop+.txt
rm -v ./edprint+.txt
exit 0
}

init
```

The above script uses the text file containing the names as a stack.  Ed is used to put each file name into a variable, against which you can then run whatever commands you desire.  At the end of the main function, Ed is called again to remove the top line from the file; and a loop between two functions (main and next) iterates until the text file is empty, at which point the two Ed commands files are deleted, and the script terminates.

Comment: thanks for reply but the solution was a simple std_in redirect `</dev/null`
see my answer