# function in loop corrupts every other iteration

Tags: linux, bash

I made a short bash program to download podcasts and retrieve only last 20 seconds. 
Strange thing is it fails downloading every other iteration. There seems to be a problem with the function `trim_nsec`, because when I get rid of it in the loop, all the rest correctly works.

Edit : addition of double quotes, which doesn't solve the problem

```
<!-- language: lang-bash -->
#!/bin/bash

# Get podcast list
wget -O feed http://www.rtl.fr/podcast/on-n-est-pas-forcement-d-accord.xml

function trim_nsec () {
    # arguments : 1 : mp3file - 2 : duration - 3 : outputfile
    duration=$(ffprobe -i "${1}" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0")
    nth_second=$(echo "${duration} - ${2}"|bc)
    ffmpeg -i "${1}" -ss "${nth_second}" "${3}"
}

cpt=1

# let's work only on the 4th first files
grep -Po 'http[^<]*.mp3' feed|grep admedia| head -n 4 > list

cat list | while read i
do
    year=$(echo "$i" | cut -d"/" -f6)
    day=$(echo "$i" | cut -d"/" -f7)
    fullname=$(echo "$i" | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}')
    fullnameend=$(echo "$fullname" |sed -e 's/\.mp3$/_end\.mp3/')
    new_name=$(echo "$year"_"$day"_"$fullnameend")

    # let's download
    wget -O "$fullname" "$i"
    # let's trim last 20 sec
    trim_nsec "$fullname" 20 "$new_name"
    echo "$cpt file processed"
    #delete orig. file :
    rm "$fullname"
    ((cpt++)) 
done
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Use double quotes, there is most likely a problem with unexpected globbing. See: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: mmmh. even with alla double quotes required by shellcheck, it still fails every other iteration.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to reflect the addition of the double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely due to the fact that on errors, `ffmpeg` will try to get an input from user which will consume the input provided by `cat list`. See a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650892/why-redirect-stdin-inside-a-while-read-loop-in-bash) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28159381/5351549). To prevent `trim_nsec` from consuming the input from `cat list`, you could do:

```
cat list | while read i
do
    year=$(echo "$i" | cut -d"/" -f6)
    day=$(echo "$i" | cut -d"/" -f7)
    fullname=$(echo "$i" | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}')
    fullnameend=$(echo "$fullname" |sed -e 's/\.mp3$/_end\.mp3/')
    new_name=$(echo "$year"_"$day"_"$fullnameend")

    # let's download
    wget -c -O "$fullname" "$i"

    # let's trim last 20 sec
    trim_nsec "$fullname" 20 "$new_name" <&3
    echo "$cpt file processed"
    #delete orig. file :
    #rm "$fullname"
    ((cpt++))

done 3<&1
```

Comment: Not writing to a temporary file which you then discard would also lose the silly `cat`.  The `grep` can be reduced to a single command `grep -Pom 4 'http(?=[^<]*admedia)[^<]*\.mp3' feed | while read -r i; do ...` to actually make some use of the `-P` option which wasn't doing anything useful before.